# how to make an iterative array from two array

Tags: javascript

I have a cmyk array which is :

```
cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]
```

and the other one is the number array which is:

```
arrGeo = [4,2,1]
```

I want to have an array which has iterative cmyk respect to arrGeo numbers which means:

```
cmykArray = [
[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,],
[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1],
[0,0,0,1]
]
```

and this is my code to make it :

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrGeo.length; i++) {
      var cmyk = [];
      var cmykArray = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < arrGeo[i].length; j++) {
        for (let k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
         cmyk = cmyk.concat(cmykColor[i][k]);
        console.log(hex[i]);
         }
      }
       cmykArr.push(cmyk);
    }
```

Comment: I think your j loop condition needs to be just `j < arrGeo[i]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could map with another loop for the wanted count.

```js
const
    cmykColor = [[0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1]],
    arrGeo = [4, 2, 1],
    result = cmykColor.map((a, i) => {
        let c = arrGeo[i],
            t = [];
        while (c--) t.push(...a);
        return t;
    });

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its great

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very succinct solution:

```js
const cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]

const arrGeo = [4,2,1]

const result = cmykColor.map((arr, i) =>
  [...Array(arrGeo[i])].reduce(res => [...res, ...arr], [])
)

console.log(result);
```

It uses an empty array as a means for `.reduce()` to copy the current array into a result array the proper number of times.

But the primary idea is to use `.map()` because the entire purpose of a `.map()` call is to create a new array with the same length as the one it's called on, but with a new value at each index.

So `cmykColor` wants to "map" each of its arrays to a new array that has the content spread out the proper number of times.

---

And we can make it slightly more efficient by reusing the original array as the seeded value to `.reduce()`.

```js
const cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]

const arrGeo = [4,2,1]

const result = cmykColor.map((arr, i) =>
  [...Array(arrGeo[i] - 1)].reduce(res => [...res, ...arr], arr)
)

console.log(result);
```

---

You could also just map each `cmykColor` array the proper number of times to a new array, and make those arrays the arguments to `.concat()`.

```js
const cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]

const arrGeo = [4,2,1]

const result = cmykColor.map((arr, i) =>
  [].concat(...[...Array(arrGeo[i])].map(_ => arr))
)

console.log(result);
```

---

But then `.concat()` is an old school way to do this. You can now use `.flat()`.

```js
const cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]]

const arrGeo = [4,2,1]

const result = cmykColor.map((arr, i) =>
  [...Array(arrGeo[i])].map(_ => arr).flat()
)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its great

Answer (score 1):

One liner:

```js
cmykColor = [[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,1],[0,0,0,1]];
arrGeo = [4,2,1];
cmykArray = [];

arrGeo.forEach(function (item, index) {
  cmykArray[index] = [].concat.apply([], Array(item).fill(cmykColor[index]));
});

console.log(cmykArray);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
/** Thanks Nina :) **/
```

Comment: Thank you so much, its great